# Why doesn't Android Studio see 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout'?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I'm a beginner developer in Android. I included
`'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and `'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` in `build.gradle`.

`build.gradle:`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.financialapp"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'

}
```

I want to use `'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout' in the XML file but then there is an error.

**error:**

```
error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
```

Comment: All of the `com.android.support` libraries were replaced years ago with ones from the Jetpack (`androidx`). Please use the `androidx` libraries -- there are equivalents for all three of the `com.android.support` libraries that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with
this: `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX.`

Old:

```kotlin
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

New:

```kotlin
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not have dependency for material

inside your build.gradle(:app)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```